# Eager Loading multiple relationships with a filter on a relation with Eloquent ORM

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, eager-loading, eloquent

I have the following code that doesn't work:

```
$threads = MessageThread::with('last_message', 'thread_visibility')
    ->where('message_thread_visibility.user_id', Auth::user()->id)->get();
```

What is the best way to add a "where" clause to an eagerly loaded multiple relationship eloquent query in Laravel?

Answer (score 6):

```
$threads = MessageThread::with(array(
     'last_message', 
     'thread_visibility' => function($query) { 
            $query->where('user_id', 2); 
      }))->get();
```

The above seems to work.